# swift generic dictionary function

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, func

I am trying to create a generic function for dictionary(of any data type). I get this error though when I call the function:

> error: cannot convert value of type '[Int : String]' to expected
>   argument type '[_ : _]' wprintgeneric(inp: w)
>                      ^

my code is as follows:

```
var w=[1:"wisam",2:"khlaid",3:"abd"] //dictionary

func wprintgeneric<T>(inp:[T:T]){

    for (i,j) in inp{print(i,j)}
}

wprintgeneric(inp: w)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting this error because you aren't using the generics correctly, a generic is a placeholder for a specific type you don't know upfront (note that it is actually different from the `Any` type).

You should do:

```
func wprintgeneric<T,U>(inp:[T:U]){

   for (i,j) in inp  {
      print(i,j)
   }
}
```

Comment: The `: Hashable` restriction is not needed, that is implicit given due to `[T:U]`.

Comment: @MartinR Wow, surprising! Didn't knew about this implicit part of generic types

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Thanks A LOT ...You really helped me